# EaselJS stage.getObjectUnderPoint() issue

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs

My code looks like the following:

```
stage.on("stagemousedown", function(evt) {
    mDown = true;
    if (stage.getObjectUnderPoint(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY) == null) {
      var rect = new createjs.Shape();
      rect.graphics.beginFill("DeepSkyBlue").drawRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
      var xx = Math.floor(evt.stageX / zoom);
      var yy = Math.floor(evt.stageY / zoom);
      rect.name = "rect";
      rect.x = xx;
      rect.y = yy;
      container.addChild(rect);
      stage.update();
      alert("no rect under mouse");
    } else {
      alert("a rect under mouse");
    }
})
```

This code always throws the "no rect under mouse" alert no matter if its above a created rect or not. My canvas is scaled up and the purpose of this code is to not allow multiple rects to be created on top of each other.

Comment: How are you scaling the stage? If you scale the actual Stage, it can mess with the coordinates. Here is a quick demo showing getObjectUnderPoint. http://jsfiddle.net/hrq50d0L/ -- If you uncomment the scale line, it will begin to get messed up. This demo also scales via CSS, but it doesn't impact the mouse check.

Comment: I scale via "stage.scaleX = 20;" for y the same and if i leave these lines out everything works as intended.

Comment: Stage scaling is not advisable -- you would have to manually transform your mouse coordinates. You should be able to wrap contents in a Container, and scale that instead. Here is a revision, where the stage coordinates are divided by the stage scale, which makes it work again: http://jsfiddle.net/hrq50d0L/1/